# Do Google Maps API support Truck Navigation?

Tags: java, swift, api, google-maps

So I’ve searched on all Google Maps API systems and have not been able to find a navigation API that supports truck routes. E.g. Trucks being offered alternate routes in the US and Europe, as they cannot drive on certain roads due to narrow widths and minimum speed protocols or low bridges. If not, I’m hoping they release something shortly, and if there is not an API navigation system for trucks, does anyone know what other API’s could I use to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Google Maps API doesn't support truck directions.

There is a feature request in the Google issue tracker to enable truck navigation in Directions API. You can see this feature request at

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80530792

Feel free to star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to email notifications.